# Gradient background is not applied for screen

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

I have the following render function:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} start={[0, 0]} end={[1, 1]} />
            <View ... >
    </View>
```

I created it, because I want to create a Gradient background for my screen. But when I open this screen, I see, that this background isn't applied. So, what's the matter and what's wrong in my code?

Comment: as per example `start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}}` this is how you need to specify start and end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the document [react native linear gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) you need to specify start and end as an object specifying x and y coordinates.

```
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <LinearGradient 
              colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} 
              start={{x: 0, y: 0}} 
              end={{x:1, y: 1}} 
            />
          <View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything's good in your code.

You just need to add an style also to your child component of style = {{flex:1}} 
This will render the gradient.